# R: Inconsistent results from 'which' and 'prop.table' for GermanCredit data from caret package

Tags: r

I am working on converting some of the variables in the German credit file from the caret package to factors.  Using factors reduce the no. of variables from 62 to 21.

Problem is that I get inconsistent results for the data summary for the `Purpose.X` columns:

```r
for (i in 20:30) { 
  print(c(colnames(GermanCredit)[i], length( which(GermanCredit[,i] == 1))))
}

[1] "Purpose.NewCar" "234"           
[1] "Purpose.UsedCar" "103"            
[1] "Purpose.Furniture.Equipment" "181"                        
[1] "Purpose.Radio.Television" "280"                     
[1] "Purpose.DomesticAppliance" "12"                       
[1] "Purpose.Repairs" "22"             
[1] "Purpose.Education" "50"               
[1] "Purpose.Vacation" "0"               
[1] "Purpose.Retraining" "9"                 
[1] "Purpose.Business" "97"              
[1] "Purpose.Other" "12"
```

and the results from the prop.table are

```
prop.table(table(Purpose))
NewCar             UsedCar Furniture.Equipment    Radio.Television
0.234               0.103               0.181               0.280
DomesticAppliance    Repairs  Education            Vacation
0.012                 0.022     0.050               0.009
Retraining            Business          Other
0.097               0.012               0.000
```

It looks like the results from Vacation-Other are rotated for some reason.  Any help in figuring out why the inconsistent results would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

--
Purpose is gotten through the use of the following loop:

```r
pcolnamerepeat <- c("CheckingAccountStatus.", "CreditHistory.", "Purpose.", 
                    "SavingsAccountBonds.", "EmploymentDuration.", "Personal.", 
                    "OtherDebtorsGuarantors.", "Property.", 
                    "OtherInstallmentPlans.", "Housing.", "Job.")

for (i in pcolnamerepeat) { 
  rpt <- grep(i, colnames(GermanCredit))
  tempfac <- factor(apply(GermanCredit[, rpt], 1, function(x) which(x == 1)))

  levels(tempfac) <- substr(colnames(GermanCredit[, rpt]), nchar(i) + 1,
                            nchar(colnames(GermanCredit[,rpt])))

  GermanCredit <- cbind(GermanCredit[-c(rpt)], tempfac)

  names(GermanCredit)[length(GermanCredit)] <- substr(i, 1, nchar(i) - 1)
}

attach(GermanCredit) # Makes easy access to the columns
```

Comment: how did you define purpose?

Comment: Thanks.  I defined it above.  Sorry for not adding that earlier.

Comment: Vacation has nothing in it so it is being excluded in your apply call. Its better to remove it from the data.

Comment: For Purpose, tempfac is of length 10 but in the next step you are assigning it name of length 11. As there is no obs in vacation it gets skipped in tempfac. but during assigning names you assign vacation to the next factor i.e restraining.

Comment: Thanks Chirayu!  You are right.  I didn't think to check that before.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Im glad it helped.